# Sync PC Time off Android Device

Tags: windows, android, lan, time

Is there any way to set the time of a Windows PC by querying an (unrooted) Android phone on the same LAN? IE,

```
net time \\computer_name /set /y
```

but with an Android device as the time source. As in the imaginary:

```
net time \\android_phone /set /y
```

Comment: [may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381005/is-android-using-ntp-to-sync-time), but not syncing to a specific android device, you may be able to set the android server to the windows time settings.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the reverse, as in: use an (unrooted) Android phone to set the time of a Windows PC. Or, more acurately, set the time of a Windows PC using the phone as the authority.

Comment: Are you hoping to essentially get your PCs clocks in sync with the wireless carrier's time?

Comment: Apparently "There's an app that" applies here too: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate

Comment: The `Time Server` app on Google's Play Store does exactly what you want...

Comment: Silly me, I'd been searching the term "NTP Server" rather than "Time Server". The Time Server app by Ice Cold Apps doesn't say it needs Root either, though I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: @music2myear, for reasons intrinsic to my particular setup, one of my machines does not connect immediately upon boot. It would be nice, however, for its clock to be synchronized before it logs in. As my phone is the device most likely to be on at any one time, it would make for the best source for synchronization.

Comment: @garethTheRed: I've been looking at [Time Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.timeserver&hl=en), too. I'd hoped for a single command line to rule it all, but I may need to do some configuring.